# Create a list with jquery and post it to asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for a way to store the values of all existing checkboxes of a given class into some kind of list or array and send the result via jquery to an asp.net mvc controller. The checkboxes do not have to be checked, I need all of them.

More details:

My checkboxes look like this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="a-checkbox"
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="a-checkbox"
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="a-checkbox"
```

It would be nice if my MVC controller could look like this

```
public JsonResult SaveList(List<String> values) { //... }
```

I know that I could access the checkboxes in the following way

```
 $('input.a-checkbox').each(
    function () {
        // create the list with the help of $(this).val()
    }
 );

 // jquery post would happen here
```

But I dont know how to create such a data structure. Could you help me?

Thank you

edit: nice, thanks. Can you tell me whats wrong with this? My controller gets called indeed, but the list is null (on server side)

```
var list = [];
            $('a-checkbox').each(
                function () {
                    list.push($(this).val());
                }
            );

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: myUrl,
                data: list,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.Result);
                },
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true
            });
```

Comment: If the values are null it means you have a model binding error.  Here's an extension method I use to dump bind errors to the console in debug: http://pastebin.com/S0gM3vqg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will put all the `checkbox` values (`value` attributes) into an `Array`:

```
var values = [];
$(".a-checkbox").each(function () {
    values.push($(this).val());
});

// values now equals ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you, maybe you could take a look at m edit above? Have problems with the post

Comment: jQuery will serialise your `list` using [param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). There is an example on how `Array`s are serialised on the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var list = [];
$('input.a-checkbox').each(
    function () {
        // create the list with the help of $(this).val()
        list.push($(this).val());
    }
);
```

Now you can post `list` object to your mvc controller action.

Answer (score 1):

I use .Serialize() to format form data for my mvc ajax actions.

```
var checkPostData = $(".a-checkbox").serialize();
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: This produces a querystring (ex: `a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5`), not an array.

Comment: Well he did say "It would be nice..." not "It is required" :P  The mvc model binder handles the details just fine usually.  Your right might not be what the OP is after though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue Nulls in my MVC mode and all. I found using $("input:checked") as my data instead of trying to extract the values to an array in js worked better and I fixed the Nulls issue by giving my checkboxes name values because MVC binds on input names.

HTML

```
<a class="post-checkboxes" href="#">post checkboxes</a>
<input name="[MVC viewmodel list variable name]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="[MVC viewmodel list variable name]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
```

Javascript

```
$('.post-checkboxes').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("[location to post to]", $("input:checked"));            
});
```